# Double Hop Impersonation, Protocol Transitioning and Constrained Delegation in ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows-authentication

I want to use IIS impersonation to connecto to a SQL server database as the user who is currently accessing a website. This is for auditing and security reasons.

I've done some reading and discovered that because the SQL Server is on a sepearate physical server I need to enable Protocol Transitioning and Constrained delegation for the server that's running IIS. This is the article that I found ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649317.aspx

I didn't realise at the time I first read it but this article has the following header...

> Retired Content
>
> This content is outdated and is no
>   longer being maintained. It is
>   provided as a courtesy for individuals
>   who are still using these
>   technologies. This page may contain
>   URLs that were valid when originally
>   published, but now link to sites or
>   pages that no longer exist.

What I want to know is, does the information in the article still apply, if I want to impersonate the user all the way to the SQL Server, do i still need Constrained Delegation or has this been implemented in some other way for ASP.NET 4?

Comment: Did you achieve what you were hoping for?  Impersonation and trusted connection to SQL Server?  Was it forms or windows authentication for your app?

Comment: @Aaron Wagner, yes I managed to achieve the end result of accessing the SQL database as the windows principle. Our app uses SqlServer impersonation rather than IIS impersonation. We access the database with a single user and that user executes a "EXECUTE AS LOGIN..." SQL command to change the user context on the database. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's an approach I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constrained Delegation is the *only* way to flow impersonated credentials information to a second host. ASP.Net has *nothing* to do with it, is just an ordinary app that uses the Kerberos framework. Nothing changed. Once the ASP.NEt applicaiton impersonates the context authenticated by IIS (see [Configure ASP.NET Impersonation Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)) the same rules for delegation apply:

- The app pool account must be configured to be trusted for constrained delegation
- The SQL Server must have the SPN properly registered