# Windows Authentication works from local (IIS Express) to server (IIS 8.5), but not at from server to server request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, httprequest, windows-authentication

We have 2 apps - here I will name them `API` and `Consumer`.

I need to get from `API` the data related to the current logged in Windows user, so I pass the currently authenticated Windows user from `Consumer` to `API` using HttpClientHandler when doing request:

```
    public async Task<string> GetWindowsUserDataFromLegacyBackend()
    {
        var res = string.Empty;

        HttpClientHandler authHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        };

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(authHandler))
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage message = client.GetAsync(this._configuration.GetSection("Backend").Value + "Account/GetCurrentUser").Result;

                if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    res = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }              
        }
        return res;
    }
```

When I run the `Consumer` on `localhost` and pass the currently authenticated Windows user to `API` which is located on the `remote server`, I receive proper response from `API` with the user-related data.

However, when I run the `Consumer` from a server to and pass the currently authenticated Windows user to `API` (which is located on another server), I do not receive user related data. It seems like in this case the currently authenticated Windows user is not properly sent by `Consumer` or is not properly read by 'API'.

This is what I use in the web.config:

```
    <authentication>
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
    </authentication>
```

Also, when I track the http responsewith fiddler, I first receive 401 response, then 401 response again, and then 200 response, just the way it is expected:

http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET38&Lang=EN

> "There are 3 calls to the server and only the last one returns status
>   code 200 and the expected data. Windows Integrated Authentication
>   (WIA) utilizes Negotiate/Kerberos or NTLM to authenticate users based
>   on an encrypted ticket that is send between the client and server. The
>   initial request does not include any authorization so it is anonymous.
>   Then IIS (Express) will return a 401 (Unauthorized) message together
>   with a list of authentication protocols that the server (IIS)
>   supports. In this case it is Negotiate en NTLM. Then the browser reads
>   the supported authentication providers, it will use the Negotiate
>   authentication provider and send an encrypted security ticket to
>   Active Directory, this will return the Kerberos token. Finally this
>   Kerberos taken will be send back to IIS. If IIS can authenticate it,
>   then it will return an 200 message together with your data."

This makes me believe that the `API` receives correct and existing Windows user (but not sure about this).

Anybody with suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: IIS Express runs under the current user's identity, probably yours.  That's why it seems to work locally.  If you ask another user to access the instance running locally, I believe you will still see your identity details reported and not those of the use other user.

Comment: More specifically, it is authenticating the user of the server, but the user is the service account running the IIS app pool, which is `network service` or an explicitly configured user. What you need to do is get the calling user identity from the user (browser, app, etc.) that initiates it through something like `constrained delegation`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146864/double-hop-impersonation-protocol-transitioning-and-constrained-delegation-in-a